# What can't I see the run-as server option in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, eclipse-plugin, m2eclipse

I'm working on a project in Eclipse Version: 3.5.2

My colleague and I both checked out the same maven project from svn.  I'm trying to debug it by running it in Tomcat.

He can see the run-as server option when he right-clicks the project, but I can't.

[image]

[image]
What did I forget to do?

I can't even see the server option under Window->Show View->Other
[image]
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Deployment of applications on Java EE Application Servers or containers is possible only when you have WTP installed. From the screenshots posted, I can infer that either WTP is unavailable or it hasn't been loaded by Eclipse (for some unfortunate reason).

You ought to perform one of the following:

- You can get a copy of the [Eclipse IDE for Java EE developers](http://www.eclipse.org/home/categories/index.php?category=enterprise), which contains WTP by default. If you need the Galileo edition, you will need to look into the [Galileo archives](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/galileo/sr2). Also, you should use a JDK to start Eclipse. WTP might not be available if you use a JRE.
- If you do not wish to install Eclipse with WTP from scratch, install the WTP plug-ins. Use the Galileo update site for this.
- If you are sure that you have WTP installed, but you are unable to find that Galileo has loaded the plug-ins, then you will need to inspect the contents of the `.metadata\.log` file in your workspace. This would give you a hint as to why the plug-in was not loaded. Start Eclipse with the `-clean` flag, to get Eclipse to detect the plug-in if it hasn't done so previously.

Note: If WTP has been installed, you should be able to confirm this by view the list of loaded features, as shown below.

[image: Eclipse WTP verification]

Answer (score 0):

Here's are some instructions I wrote up when I configured my Eclipse to work with Tomcat.  Hopefully it'll help you.

**Open Servers Window**

- Open the Servers view.
- If servers view is not open, select menu item Window/Show View/Other...
- Select Servers under the Server section.

**Add New Server**

- Right Click in the Servers View select New/Server
- Expand Apache and select Tomcat v5.5 Server
- Click Next.
- Select the directory of your Tomcat installation. (ie c:\tomcat)
- Click Finish

Comment: The servers view is not available to me in the Other list.  I don't understand how it is missing

Comment: See Vineet Reynolds answer.  Guessing you didn't install the Eclipse IDE for Java EE version of Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

This will be the solution for all your questions. A must read [`pdf`](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/education/web/t320/Configuring_an_Application_Server_in_Eclipse.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Did you create a Web Project? If you right click on the project and go to Properties > Project Facets is Dynamic Web Module selected. This works for me.

Answer (score -1):

In case of web application 3.0 in my case i have taken war file of project and deleted existing app from eclipse and replaced it with war it worked for me